# Extract rows of strings between two rows of partial string matches (not inclusive of the matching string row) in R

Tags: r, string, string-matching

I have a file that is essentially made up of rows of strings. I am trying to extract the sections of rows into individual files between rows of strings. The file looks like this:

```
**File Begins**

"Name: XXX_2" 
"Description:  Object 1210 , 111"
"Sampling_info: statexy=1346"
"Num value: 15"
"32 707; 33 71; 37 11; 38 3; 40 146; " 
"41 64; 42 36; 43 24; 44 69; 45 324; " 
"46 49; 47 52; 50 11; 51 90; 52 22; " 
"Name: XXX_3" 
"Description:  Object 1341 , 111"
"Sampling_info: statexy=1346"
"Num value: 18"
"32 999; 33 4; 34 17; 39 84; 41 84; " 
"42 4; 44 137; 45 102; 50 13; 52 22; " 
"53 4; 54 4; 55 84; 58 40; 59 13; "
"65 57; 66 13; 67 173; " 
"Name: XXX_4" 
"Description:  Object 1561 , 111"
"Sampling_info: statexy=1346"
"Num value: 21"
"32 925; 34 5; 40 409; 41 55; 44 43; "   
"45 154; 46 5; 47 5; 50 38; 52 16; "  
"56 99; 58 5; 59 110; 61 5; 62 55; " 
"63 11; 68 5; 69 38; 70 22; 73 999; " 
"74 49; "
"Name: XXX_5" 

**And then the next entry begins**
```

I want to get the numbers between "Num value: 15" and "Name: XXX_3" while excluding those two rows and put it into its own text file. Same for the next two entries. This will be implemented into a for loop or other to extract all the independent entries in the file to their own file.

I tried str_match but it returns NA:

```
str_match(data, "Name: UNK_1\\s*(.*?)\\s*Name: UNK_2")
```

I also tried gsub but it returned the whole file...:

```
gsub(".*Name: UNK_1 (.+) Name: UNK_2.*", "\\1", data)
```

Is there something wring with my implementation of str_match and gsub?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a consistent number of lines for different entries? may be easier to read then in line by line an select the lines you want.

Comment: There is not a consistent number of lines. But the number of lines is a function of the Num value: 15. So there are 5 entries per line so there are 3 lines. However, the Num value val be 16 so there would be 4 lines but only one value on the last line.

Comment: If you could dput(a Num value:15) and paste structure(...) above as data, same for Num value: 16, we'll all be looking at the same `data`. What/where did this file type originate from?

Comment: What is the significance of the paired values, `"32 707` and does that pairing need to be preserved over and above `32` came before `707`, or is `32 707` a discrete couplet and `33 71` another, along on down the line of either length 15 or 16 pairs?

Comment: @Chris the paired values ultimately need to be different columns. The original file type was a .msp.

Comment: @Chris I added more data so it is more true to what I am looking at on my end and clarified to question.

Comment: Is the desire to collect all extracted .msp files into one data.frame? and what would the columns be called?

Comment: No the desire is to extract all independent entries from the .msp file to individual text files. I have one .msp file with almost 5000 independent entries. So I would like ~5000 independent text files

Comment: Understood. You will like `dput(head(my_data, n = (some reasonable and representative amount as integer))` copy `structure(...)` on your questions going forward.

Comment: You mean in stack overflow when I post a question?

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
# Build dataset
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("Name: XXX_2" ,
           "Description:  Object 1210 , 111",
           "Sampling_info: statexy=1346",
           "Num value: 15",
           "32 707; 33 71; 37 11; 38 3; 40 146; " ,
           "41 64; 42 36; 43 24; 44 69; 45 324; " ,
           "46 49; 47 52; 50 11; 51 90; 52 22; " ,
           "Name: XXX_3" ,
           "Shouldn't get this number: 8675309")
)

df %>%
  # Combine row into single string
  map_chr(paste, collapse = " ") %>%
  # Remove everything before "Num value:"
  str_extract(" Num value:.*") %>%
  # Remove numbers after "Num value:
  str_remove("Num value: \\d+") %>%
  # Remove everything after "Name:"
  str_extract(" .*Name:") %>%
  # Extract digits
  str_extract_all("\\d+") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  as.numeric()

#[1]  32 707  33  71  37  11  38   3  40 146  41  64  42  36  43  24  44  69  45
#[20] 324  46  49  47  52  50  11  51  90  52  22
```

Comment: The leading `15` is an unwanted artifact. perhaps `str_extract('Num value: \\d+")`. also a question to the OP about the significance of the 'pairing' of values and how that needs to be handled, as in the 'Num value: 16' case, it is likely "12 141;"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @chris. I've edited my post to remove the 15 following "Num value".

Comment: This is great however, it does give all the values that are between "Name:" and "Num value" meaning that all names and num values are reported back. I guess I am not sure how to adapt this into a for loop or otherwise to report individual entries to independent files. It also doesn't retain the pairing of the values, which ultimately need to be two different columns.

Comment: @DFM-1124, it be easier and make it a little quicker if you included an example of exactly the format you were looking for in the output. It'll give me something better to shoot for.

Answer (score 1):

with `base` and `for`, and various notes.

```
library(stringr)
# msp_list <- scan(file='', what = character()) #paste in 1:24 above <return>
# dput(msp_list)
msp_list <- c("Name: XXX_2", "Description:  Object 1210 , 111", "Sampling_info: statexy=1346", 
"Num value: 15", "32 707; 33 71; 37 11; 38 3; 40 146; ", "41 64; 42 36; 43 24; 44 69; 45 324; ", 
"46 49; 47 52; 50 11; 51 90; 52 22; ", "Name: XXX_3", "Description:  Object 1341 , 111", 
"Sampling_info: statexy=1346", "Num value: 18", "32 999; 33 4; 34 17; 39 84; 41 84; ", 
"42 4; 44 137; 45 102; 50 13; 52 22; ", "53 4; 54 4; 55 84; 58 40; 59 13; ", 
"65 57; 66 13; 67 173; ", "Name: XXX_4", "Description:  Object 1561 , 111", 
"Sampling_info: statexy=1346", "Num value: 21", "32 925; 34 5; 40 409; 41 55; 44 43; ", 
"45 154; 46 5; 47 5; 50 38; 52 16; ", "56 99; 58 5; 59 110; 61 5; 62 55; ", 
"63 11; 68 5; 69 38; 70 22; 73 999; ", "74 49; ")
# get rid of trailing whitespace that will be annoying later
msp_lst <- trimws(msp_list, 'r')
```

index  msp_list, for start and end of future sub dfs. I am assuming you .mps is properly formed, which is to say all are complete (I've wished away your line 25 above).

```
msp_name_rle <- rle(str_starts(msp_list, 'Name'))$lengths
msp_rle_mtx<- matrix(msp_name_rle, nrow = length(msp_name_rle)/2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
msp_rowsums <-matrix(rowSums(msp_rle_mtx), ncol = 1)
starts <- which(str_starts(msp_list, 'Name') == TRUE)
starts
[1]  1  8 16
ends <- as.vector(starts + msp_rowsums -1)
ends
[1]  7 15 24

# and then get names as they will be useful later
> msp_names <- trimws(str_extract(msp_list[which(str_starts(msp_list, 'Name') == TRUE)], '\\s\\w+'))
# a similar extract could be done on ? whatever is informative and applied to attributes later (not done here)
# initialize an object to receive output from the `for` loop
many_msp <- list()
```

At this point we have what we need in the global environment to inform the operations in the for loop so it won't complain that some value isn't found. And things are sufficiently detailed to operate on one index (i.e. not nested `i,j`), well, at least I hope, and we'll do a bunch of data cleaning here, but hopefully return an extracted list of .msp values in a two column df each (that basically relies on the regularity of the .msp file format

```
# first checking that the indexing is working
for(i in 1:length(starts)) {
  many_msp[[i]] <- df3[starts[i]:ends[i], ]
}
many_msp[[3]]
[[3]]
[1] "Name: XXX_4"                         
[2] "Description:  Object 1561 , 111"     
[3] "Sampling_info: statexy=1346"         
[4] "Num value: 21"                       
[5] "32 925; 34 5; 40 409; 41 55; 44 43; "
[6] "45 154; 46 5; 47 5; 50 38; 52 16; "  
[7] "56 99; 58 5; 59 110; 61 5; 62 55; "  
[8] "63 11; 68 5; 69 38; 70 22; 73 999; " 
[9] "74 49; "                             
# OK. Now, we can either make another `for`, or extend what happens within this one.
```

Extending:

```
for(i in 1:length(starts)) {
many_msp[[i]] <- msp_list[starts[i]:ends[i]]
#return only values
many_msp[[i]] <- many_msp[[i]][5:lengths(many_msp)[i]]
#take to vector, after a bunch of tidying up
many_msp[[i]] <- as.numeric(strsplit(trimws(paste(gsub(';', '', many_msp[[i]]), collapse = ''), 'r'), ' ')[[1]])
#take to data.frame
many_msp[[i]] <- data.frame(col1 = many_msp[[i]][seq(1, length(many_msp[[i]]), 2)], col2 = many_msp[[i]][seq(2, length(many_msp[[i]]), 2)])
# name the data.frames
names(many_msp)[i] <- msp_names[[i]]
}

names(many_msp)
[1] "XXX_2" "XXX_3" "XXX_4"


many_msp$XXX_4
   col1 col2
1    32  925
2    34    5
3    40  409
4    41   55
5    44   43
6    45  154
7    46    5
8    47    5
9    50   38
10   52   16
11   56   99
12   58    5
13   59  110
14   61    5
15   62   55
16   63   11
17   68    5
18   69   38
19   70   22
20   73  999
21   74   49
```

so can be done with a `for` loop. The accessing/addressing in this list stuff may be a little less apparent when reaching into col1, col2 values as you have

```
many_msp$XXX_4$col1
 [1] 32 34 40 41 44 45 46 47 50 52 56 58 59 61 62 63 68 69 70 73 74
```

which is unexpected, at first.

Answer (score 0):

One approach without loops:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- read.delim('path_to_input_file/your_file.txt',
                 sep = ':', header = FALSE)

df %>%
    separate(V1, into = c('param', 'value'), sep = ' *: *') %>%
    filter(param == 'Name' | grepl(';', param)) %>%
    fill(value, .direction = 'down') %>%
    filter(param != 'Name') %>%
    separate_rows(param, sep = ' *; *')

## follow up with blank removal, conversion to numeric as needed
```

Output (column `value` contains the name from the initial name: xxx lines)

```
# A tibble: 18 x 2
   param    value   
   <chr>    <chr>   
 1 "32 707" "XXX_2 "
 2 "33 71"  "XXX_2 "
 3 "37 11"  "XXX_2 "
 4 "38 3"   "XXX_2 "
 5 "40 146" "XXX_2 "
 6 ""       "XXX_2 "
```

You might want to partition the above pipeline and inspect  the intermediate dataframes to see what's going on at which step.